# when $38^n-25$ is prime

Tags: analysis, prime-numbers

I need a help with this problem: find all positive integers $n$ such that the $38^n-25$ is prime. I don't know how to start with it.

Thanks for your help!

**My work**:...

Comment: You can rule out all even $n$, because if $n=2m$ then $(38^m-5)(38^m+5)$ is a factorisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is obvious that for $n=1$ we have that $38-25=13$ is a prime.
Now we conjecture that it is never prime for $n>1$.

Note that we have $25=5^2$ and for $n=2m$ even we have $38^n-5^2=38^{2m}-5^2=(38^m)^2-5^2$.
But this can be factored easily, with the binomial formula. So this is not prime.

So what happens when $n=2m+1$ is odd?

Then we have $38^{2m+1}-25=38\cdot38^{2m}-25=38\cdot 38^{2m}-25$.
This is divisible by 13, as RobertZ suggests.

As we have $38\equiv -1\mod 13$ and $25\equiv -1\mod 13$, we get:

$38\cdot 38^{2m}-25\equiv (-1)\cdot (-1)^{2m}-(-1)=0\mod 13$.

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear! I like this idea with modulo notation, is very simple.

Answer (score 5):

First note that $39=3\cdot 13$.

My Hint. When $n$ is even, find $38^n-25\pmod{3}$. When $n$ is odd, find $38^n-25\pmod{13}$.

**Please show your conclusions below your question.**